# Server Name in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have `Visual Studio 2010` and `SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1` installed, and am using `Crystal Reports` for `VS2010`.

As I currently do not have `SQL Management Studio 2008`, I have inserted an `MDF Database` into my `WinForm` project using

```
Solution Explorer > ProjectName > Add New Item
```

I need that `MDF` file's connection for use under

```
Crystal Reports > Database Expert > Create New Connection > OLE DB (ADO)
```

There is no server name under `Server:`. I tried `.\SQLEXPRESS` as the server name but it shows the default database. I also tried my machine name as the server name but `Database:` is empty.

How can I connect to that file with Crystal Reports?